# Getting the browser to remember my inputs and display them separated with <p> tags

Tags: jquery

Happy holidays! I have got so far with my jQuery I need it to remember all the inputs, and then display them on Submit. I have got so far, but I am stuck on this line:

`$('#rememberArea').text(value);`

How can I get it to remember the inputs, and put them in separate `<p>` tags, within the `#rememberArea` div?

```
<div id="rememberArea">
      <!-- <p> valueGuessOne </p> -->
      <!-- <p> valueGuesTwo </p> -->
      <!-- <p> valueGuessThree </p> -->
</div>
```

```js
$(function(){
      $("#rememberForm").submit(function(e) { 
          var valueGuessOne = $(".one").val();
          var valueGuessTwo = $(".two").val();
          var valueGuessThree = $(".three").val();
          var valueGuessFour = $(".four").val();
          var valueGuessFive = $(".five").val();

          $('#rememberArea').text(value); // text function takes value as parameter
          e.preventDefault();
      });
  });
```

```css
label, input {
  display:block;
}

input {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.standard {
  width:500px;
  padding:8px;
}

.rememberArea {
  margin-top:20px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rememberForm">

<label>
  Guess 1: 
</label>
<input class="standard one" />

<label>
  Guess 2: 
</label>
<input class="standard two" />

<label>
  Guess 3: 
</label>
<input class="standard three" />

<label>
  Guess 4: 
</label>
<input class="standard four" />

<label>
  Guess 4: 
</label>
<input class="standard five" />

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Remember" />

</form>

<div class="rememberArea">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you want. You just have to append each of the values to the `rememberArea` div. All the values will be added as separate `p` blocks and will be stored in their variables to which they were assigned. If you wanted something else, please comment below.

```js
$(function(){
      var valueGuessOne, valueGuessTwo, valueGuessThree, valueGuessFour, valueGuessFive;
      
      $("#rememberForm").submit(function(e) {
          valueGuessOne = $(".one").val();
          valueGuessTwo = $(".two").val();
          valueGuessThree = $(".three").val();
          valueGuessFour = $(".four").val();
          valueGuessFive = $(".five").val();
          $('.rememberArea').html(""); // this will clear the old content
          $('.rememberArea').append("<p>"+valueGuessOne+"</p>")
                            .append("<p>"+valueGuessTwo+"</p>")
                            .append("<p>"+valueGuessThree+"</p>")
                            .append("<p>"+valueGuessFour+"</p>")
                            .append("<p>"+valueGuessFive+"</p>");
          e.preventDefault();
      });
  });
```

```css
label, input {
  display:block;
}

input {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.standard {
  width:500px;
  padding:8px;
}

.rememberArea {
  margin-top:20px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rememberForm">

<label>
  Guess 1: 
</label>
<input class="standard one" />

<label>
  Guess 2: 
</label>
<input class="standard two" />

<label>
  Guess 3: 
</label>
<input class="standard three" />

<label>
  Guess 4: 
</label>
<input class="standard four" />

<label>
  Guess 5: 
</label>
<input class="standard five" />

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Remember" />

</form>

<div class="rememberArea">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Ideally, I needed it to clear before it was sent again. If you press submit once more, it still keeps the previous inputs. Any idea how I can clear those on another submit?

Comment: can you help, what does `e` mean in the function? Why is it necessary?

Comment: @cmp `e` is a parameter that 'stores' the `eventObject` described [here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/). `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default behaviour of the the form (redirecting or refreshing the page), so when you click on the submit button, the code is executed and the default behaviour (refreshing, redirecting) is stopped from happening. The best way for you to understand is to remove that line and try to submit the form, then put it back and see what happens then.

Answer (score 0):

First of All change that line of code

```
<div class="rememberArea">
```

you use the **id** selector so you need the change this to this

```
<div id="rememberArea">
```

next there is an error also on your code which is here

```
$('#rememberArea').text(value);
```

**value** variable is not defined

now we can solve this like this

```js
$(function(){
      $("#rememberForm").submit(function(e) { 
          var valueGuessOne = $(".one").val();
          var valueGuessTwo = $(".two").val();
          var valueGuessThree = $(".three").val();
          var valueGuessFour = $(".four").val();
          var valueGuessFive = $(".five").val();

         $('#rememberArea').append("<p>"+valueGuessOne+"</p>")
                        .append("<p>"+valueGuessTwo+"</p>")
                        .append("<p>"+valueGuessThree+"</p>")
                        .append("<p>"+valueGuessFour+"</p>")
                        .append("<p>"+valueGuessFive+"</p>");
          e.preventDefault();
      });
  });
```

```css
label, input {
  display:block;
}

input {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.standard {
  width:500px;
  padding:8px;
}

.rememberArea {
  margin-top:20px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rememberForm">

<label>
  Guess 1: 
</label>
<input class="standard one" />

<label>
  Guess 2: 
</label>
<input class="standard two" />

<label>
  Guess 3: 
</label>
<input class="standard three" />

<label>
  Guess 4: 
</label>
<input class="standard four" />

<label>
  Guess 4: 
</label>
<input class="standard five" />

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Remember" />

</form>

<div id="rememberArea">

</div>
```